# Fix - App Icon doesn't show up on some devices in simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, appicon

In my app I have uploaded all of the app icons needed and I still only see the app icon on the app on some iPhones basically the old ones like iPhone 6 , iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 5s and I cannot see on the last generation of iPhones like iPhone 8, iPhone 8 plus, iPhone X and also the previous generation of iPhone 7 and all the others.Am I missing some icons ? Is there a way to check if the image size is correct ?

Here I have all the icons:

[image: Picture - click]

**EDIT: I fixed the issue** by changing the color profile of the images by right clicking on them > Open with External Editor and them if it is opened in Preview you go in Tools > Assign Profile.. and change the color profile to sRGB. And boom ! Every icon after this showed up in the simulator. More solutions of this [here](https://github.com/Swrve/swrve-ios-sdk/issues/234)

Comment: Try to 1) Delete previous build from your device 2) Clean and build your project before installing it on device

Comment: Icon sizes will not be appropria

Comment: I tried everything you said pkc456 and It still doesn't show up the app icon on the app. What do you mean Taimoor ?